# How to save a table in a csv format file with tksheet?

Tags: python, csv

I want to get values on a table with python and save it into a file csv and load it.
I use the module `tksheet`, and I don't know, How can do to save and load it.

```
self.col_data = self.sheet_demo.get_column_data(2)
print(type(self.col_data))

#self.coldata = open('Monfichier.csv' , ' w')
with open('monFichierduxcole.csv', mode = 'w') as self.datacol:
        datacol.write(str(self.col_data))
self.datacol.reader('monFichierduxcole.csv', dialect='excel')
self.datacol.close()
```

The variable `self.data_data` is a list.

Table to get:

[image: screenshot of table to get]

I am currently getting the following error:

```
with open('monFichierduxcole.csv', mode = 'w') as self.datacol: 

TypeError: open() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Read up on [`.writerows(rows)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows)

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you have? How is the result **not** what you want (or is there an error)?

Comment: Hello, the error is : with open('monFichierduxcole.csv', mode = 'w') as self.datacol:
TypeError: open() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)